# two programs one named pipe in a Makefile

Tags: c, linux, makefile, named-pipes

I am new at linux and I try to make a server(reader) and a client(writer);
so the client can send "Hi" to server with named pipes.

I have write the both programs. How can I make them communicate with the named pipe when I build them in a Makefile?

```
//server programm:
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "fun.h"
#define MAX_BUF 1024

int main()
{
int pid,fd,status;
char * myfifo = "/home/pipe";
char buf[MAX_BUF];

 pid=fork();
 wait(&status);
 if (pid<0){
     exit(1);
 }
 if (pid==0){
      mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);
      fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
      main1();
      read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
      printf("%s\n", buf);
  }
 else{
      printf("i am the father and i wait my child\n");
 }
 close(fd);
 return 0;
}

//client program:
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "fun.h"

int main1()
{
int fd;
char * myfifo = "/home/pipe";

fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
write(fd, "Hi", sizeof("Hi"));
close(fd);
unlink(myfifo);

return 0;
}

//fun.h: 
int main1()

//Makefile:
all: client.o server.o
        gcc client.o server.o -o all

client.o: client.c
        gcc -c client.c 

server.o: server.c
        gcc -c server.c

clean:
        rm server.o client.o
```

Above is the code I have write so far. It s a simple code from other questions tutorials and videos.

Comment: Get your client/server working on the cmd line first. Then make a shell script to manage the process, i.e. make the named pipes, run server in background, run client and send data via named pipes, then shutdown/cleanup. Then you can look for how to embed a call to a shell script into a makefile. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you!! I beleive that it is what i am looking for!!

Answer (score 2):

You are building a single program while you need two.

server.c

```
#include "fun.h"
// system includes

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // code you put in your main()
}
```

client.c

```
#include "fun.h"
// system includes

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // code you put in your main1()
}
```

fun.h

```
#ifndef __FUN_H__
#define __FUN_H__

#define MY_FIFO "/home/pipe"

#endif /* __FUN_H__ */
```

makefile

```
INSTALL_PATH=/home/me/mybin/

all: server client

install: all
    cp server client all.sh $(INSTALL_PATH)

uninstall:
    rm -f $(INSTALL_PATH)server $(INSTALL_PATH)client $(INSTALL_PATH)all.sh

server: server.o
    gcc server.o -o server

client: client.o
    gcc client.o -o client

server.o: server.c fun.h
    gcc -c server.c

client.o: client.c fun.h
    gcc -c client.c

.PHONY: all install uninstall
```

You will get two executables, client and server. Run each of them in a different xterm.

Comment: First of all thank you about the answer!!
You are right about that!! 
I wrote one program when I need two. 
But I want them to run in them in the same terminal. 
I want server to run at the background and client sending messages to him. 
I managed it with a shell script. 
Now what i am trying to do is to create the shell script at a Makefile and run it.

Comment: @ClockWork What do you mean with "create the shell script at a Makefile and run it"? This is unclear to me.

Comment: I want to create a makefile which, 
with the command make at the terminal, will build the shell script as an executable file 
and the when I write ./all it runs the shell script.

Comment: @ClockWork "all" seems a bad name for a program because it is confusing with the traditional "all" target in makefile and most people are used with building with "make all" command. You should call it "all.sh", "all.ksh" or "all.bash", depending on the shell you want to use. You don't need to use make to generate it, no compilation is required. Just write it, and maybe you can add an "install" target in your make file to copy it in production environment.